# Ignore http when outputting image src - php

Tags: php, image, echo

I don't know if this question has been asked before but I can't seem to find a solution to it.

I have the following code

```php
$get_root = explode("\public\jude-admin",__DIR__)[0];

echo '<img src="'.str_replace('/', '\\', $get_root.$project['project_img_directory'].$project['project_cover_img']).'" alt="">';
```

It outputs the file directory but the browser interprets it by adding a "http://domain/" tag to it.

Can anyone suggest a way I can ask the browser to ignore this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access a file on the client side, so on the system where the browser runs? Short answer: that is impossible. It is blocked by all sane browsers for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Stop confusing file system paths and URLs.